# Java JFileChooser Returns the Selected Directory Instead Of Browsing It

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, filesystems, jfilechooser

When I double click a directory JFileChooser is not opening that directory i.e. it's not browsing it but it selects the directory and returns. 
How can I implement JFileChooser so that it will show the folder's content when I double click?
If **setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY)** is set then the behaviour is good as my needs but I have to use **FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES**.

Comment: So to be clear, you want double-clicking to go into the directory, but a select followed by clicking 'Open' to return the selected directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add your own `MouseListener`

```
final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
fileChooser.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

        if(arg0.getClickCount() == 2) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(file);
                fileChooser.rescanCurrentDirectory();
            }
            else {
                fileChooser.approveSelection();
            }
        }
    }

    //Other methods (can be empty)  
});
```

This checks for double clicks and gets the selected file from the `JFileChooser` checks if that's a directory and if it is follows it, if it's a file it returns the file. Also if you select a directory and hit open it opens the directory.